# Can I activate a product key in UPlay for a game that I've already bought on Steam?

Tags: steam, technical-issues, pc, ubisoft-connect

I have bought a Ubisoft game on Steam, and bought its season pass product key on a retail website, which happens to be for UPlay.

It seems that I have wasted my money. That, I accept. Now, I want to buy the base game for UPlay as well because it is cheaper to buy DLC on Steam.

My question is, if I try to activate a product on UPlay, which I already own in Steam, will it say **you already own the product** or will it allow me to activate the base game and play the bought DLCs?

Comment: What happens when you try adding the key into Steam? What happens when you try adding the key into UPlay? Steam usually starts Uplay to play a ubisoft game anyway - and registers the game on uplay on the first time. Once you've done this you can then just start uplay by itself to play the game.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Steam and UPlay are totally different platforms and do't share the same account, there is no way, that each platform could know about the games on the other one. Therefore my answer is, that you can activate the base game on both platforms.

Also if that wouldn't be possible, then the game should automatically be in your UPlay library if you activate it on Steam.

Comment: That's what confuses me too, every single UPlay games I've bought on Steam simply launches UPlay when I start them, essentially making me play them through UPlay anyway, Steam is not even required to play the game at this point, I don't see why activating the DLC on UPlay wouldn't work

Comment: I'd assume that they need to start UPlay to check the license as well as access any online content. Steam is in these cases really only the seller

Comment: The game is actually in my UPlay library. However, I cannot install the game using UPlay. It proceeds through Steam.

Comment: Have you already tried to activate the season pass on UPlay? Because right now it sounds like you should be able to since it is in your library

Comment: I think the trouble with this is the install method & location. When you buy the game on steam, it downloads/installs it to a steam library location. If you then buy DLC from Uplay, it doesn't have access to the steam library location, and so can't add any files for the DLC. (Extras that are in the base game and just need activation should be ok though - ie unlocks, rather than DLC). If you uninstall it from uplay/steam, and then launch Uplay, does it still make you install from Steam? Can you obtain the Key from Steam somewhere (account pages?)? Perhaps you can activate it in Uplay too.